# XE7 Recognize Bluetooth Disconnection

Tags: android, delphi, bluetooth, delphi-xe7

using Delphi XE7 on Android, I am connecting to via Bluetooth Classic SPP device.

I have an `JBluetoothSocket`

```
var
  Sock: JBluetoothSocket;
  uid: JUUID; // UUID for SPP traffic
  targetMAC: string; // remote MAC address of the selected
  remoteDevice: JBluetoothDevice;
  Adapter: JBluetoothAdapter; // Local BLUETOOTH adapter
begin
  Adapter := TJBluetoothAdapter.JavaClass.getDefaultAdapter;
  targetMAC := ....;
  remoteDevice := Adapter.getRemoteDevice(stringtojstring(targetMAC));
  uid := TJUUID.JavaClass.fromString(stringtojstring('00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB'));
  Sock := remoteDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uid);
end;
```

As soon as the BlueTooth device is restarted, the `JBluetoothSocket` stream cannot be read anymore, because the socket failed. So I want to reconnect as soon as the connection failed.

I tried following, but it doesn't work:

```
if Sock.isConnected then
begin
  TryReconnect;
end;
```

We also found out, that the phone CAT B15 always returns `Sock.isConnected = False`, even if connected, since this function does not seem to be implemented in their BT stack...

I heared that I probably need to catch the broadcast `ACL_DISCONNECTED`, but I don't find a solution how this is done in Firemonkey.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: https://code.google.com/p/delphi-android-broadcast-receiver-component/

```
procedure TMeasurementForm.OnBroadcastReceive(Context: JContext; Intent: JIntent);
begin
  // TODO: Check which event it is? (ACL_DISCONNECTED)
  Close;
end;

var
   bcr: TBroadcastReceiver;-
begin
  bcr := TBroadcastReceiver.Create(Self);
  bcr.RegisterReceive;
  bcr.Add('android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED'); // constant android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED
  bcr.OnReceive := OnBroadcastReceive;
end;
```